# Mysql специальная табличка..

Tags: mysql

Есть такая табличка в mysql, специальная, которая используется для выполнения запросов не связанных ни с какой табличкой..

Вопрос, как она называется ? :) Как-то давно пользовался, и вот вспомнить никак не могу )

Немного поясню:

```
SELECT 'test_value' as nanme FROM dummy_table
```

Вот этот запрос совершенно не привязан к какой-то существующей таблички, и для этих целей в mysql и есть эта специальная табличка *dummy_tabl*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Таблица `dual`:

```
SELECT 'test_value' as nanme FROM dual
```

или просто:

```
SELECT 'test_value' as nanme
```

Comment: именно название нужно было. Спасиб )

Comment: Прям на языке вертелось ))